# How to change color of np.random.normal?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to have these blue dots colored red, and also add the blue dots to a legend.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 6, 31)
y = np.cos(x) + np.random.normal(0, 0.6, 31)
plt.axis([0, 6, -1.5, 1.5])
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, np.cos(x), label='cos(x)', color = 'red')
plt.title("Model vs Data")
plt.xlabel("X")  
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: When you do `plt.scatter()` specify `color='r'`

Comment: to add them to a legend you need to specify a label for them just like you did in `plt.plot()`

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)? That's always a good place to start when you're unfamiliar with a tool you're using

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this, I can't see it being useful in the future since all the information is available in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you are asking all you need to do is change the line specifying how you want your scatter plot to look. When you add a label to a plot, it will show up when you call `plt.legend()`. Please see existing [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#examples-using-matplotlib-pyplot-plot) or [example codes](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/masked_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-masked-demo-py) before posting questions on SO.

```
plt.scatter(x, y,color='r', label='Data')
```